# Given an integer n, generate the nth count and say sequence

Tags: python, strings, interview-questions

I am solving interview questions from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/count-and-say/).

> Problem : Given an integer n, generate the nth count and say sequence. 
>   The count-and-say sequence is the sequence of integers beginning as follows:  `1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, ...`
>
> 1 is read off as one 1 or 11.
>
> 11 is read off as two 1s or 21.
>
> 21 is read off as one 2, then one 1 or 1211.
>
> Note : The sequence of integers will be represented as a string.
>
> Example: if n = 2, the sequence is 11.

How should I further optimize my solution?

```
def count_and_say(num):
        string = '11'
        cnt = 0
        new_string = []
        if num == 1:
            return "1"
        while num != 2:
            cnt += 1
            for i in range(len(string)):
                if i+1 != len(string):
                    if string[i] == string[i+1]:
                        cnt += 1
                    else:
                        new_string.append(str(cnt)+string[i])
                        cnt = 1
                else:
                    new_string.append(str(cnt)+string[i])
            cnt = 0
            num -= 1
            string = ''.join(new_string)
            new_string = []
        return string
```

Answer (score 4):

In each step of the "count-and-say sequence" (which is more usually called the "[look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)") you have to find the *groups* of consecutive runs of identical digits. So if you have the value `111221`, these groups are `111`, `22`, and `1`. Python has a built-in function [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for finding groups in an iterator, and using this function, the look-and-say step becomes:

```
new_value = ''
for digit, group in groupby(value):
    count = sum(1 for _ in group)
    new_value += str(count) + digit
value = new_value
```

which can be rearranged into a single expression:

```
value = ''.join(str(sum(1 for _ in group)) + digit
                for digit, group in groupby(value))
```

and so the whole sequence can be generated like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def look_and_say(value='1'):
    "Generate the look-and-say sequence starting at value."
    while True:
        yield value
        value = ''.join(str(sum(1 for _ in group)) + digit
                        for digit, group in groupby(value))
```

To select only the \$n\$th value of the sequence, use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
next(islice(look_and_say(), n - 1, None))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Add tests**

For this type of exercice, it is easy to write simple tests so that you can have a quick feedback when you break something as you write/rewrite your function.

If you do this as part of an interview, it'll show you have good habits.

You could use a proper test framework or just write simple code:

```
TESTS = {
    1:  '1',
    2:  '11',
    3:  '21',
    4:  '1211',
    5:  '111221',
    6:  '312211',
    7:  '13112221',
    8:  '1113213211',
    9:  '31131211131221',
    10: '13211311123113112211',
    11: '11131221133112132113212221',
    12: '3113112221232112111312211312113211',
    13: '1321132132111213122112311311222113111221131221',
    14: '11131221131211131231121113112221121321132132211331222113112211',
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n, expected in TESTS.items():
        res = count_and_say(n)
        if res != expected:
             print("Error for %d : got %s expected %s" % (n, res, expected))
```

**Style**

Python has a style guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Among other things, it gives guidelines about indentation. The recommendation is 4 spaces. (I am not sure if the 8 space indent was intended or not in your question).

**Code re-organisation**

You could re-order your condition checks and use `elif` to save a level of indentation.

You could define `new_string = []` at the beginning of the `while` loop so that you do not need to reset it at the end of the loop.

```
def count_and_say(num):
    if num == 1:
        return "1"
    string = '11'
    cnt = 0
    while num != 2:
        new_string = []
        cnt += 1
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if i+1 == len(string):
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+string[i])
            elif string[i] == string[i+1]:
                cnt += 1
            else:
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+string[i])
                cnt = 1
        cnt = 0
        num -= 1
        string = ''.join(new_string)
    return string
```

**Loop with the proper tools**

Instead of using a convoluted `while` loop to perform `n` iterations, you could use a simple `for` loop.

Taking this chance to have `cnt` initialised at the beginning of the loop, we'd have something like:

```
def count_and_say(num):
    if num == 1:
        return "1"
    string = '11'
    for i in range(num - 2):
        cnt = 1
        new_string = []
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if i+1 == len(string):
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+string[i])
            elif string[i] == string[i+1]:
                cnt += 1
            else:
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+string[i])
                cnt = 1
        string = ''.join(new_string)
    return string
```

**Loop with the proper tools**

I highly recommend [Ned Batchelder's talk "Loop like a native"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). Basically, anytime you use something like `for xxx in range(len(yyy))`, there is a better way to do it. In your case, `enumerate` can help you to write things in a clearer way.

Taking this chance to:

- change how `cnt` works by being a bit more natural: set it to 0 and increment it in all cases
- move the final iteration out of the loop

You'd get something like;

```
def count_and_say(num):
    if num == 1:
        return "1"
    string = '11'
    for i in range(num - 2):
        cnt = 0
        new_string = []
        for i, c in enumerate(string):
            cnt += 1
            if i+1 != len(string) and c != string[i+1]:
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+c)
                cnt = 0
        new_string.append(str(cnt)+c)
        string = ''.join(new_string)
    return string
```

**Remove non-required edge cases**

In the original code, we start from '11' and perform `num-2` iterations.
This is similar to starting from '1' and performing `num-1` iterations.
Then we don't need to handle `num == 1` as a special case:

```
def count_and_say(num):
    string = '1'
    for i in range(num - 1):
        cnt = 0
        new_string = []
        for i, c in enumerate(string):
            cnt += 1
            if i+1 != len(string) and c != string[i+1]:
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+c)
                cnt = 0
        new_string.append(str(cnt)+c)
        string = ''.join(new_string)
    return string
```

**Handle the prev, not the next**

This is mostly a matter of personal preference but you could make you do not need to handle indices by working with the previous character instead of the next.

You'd get something like:

```
def count_and_say(num):
    string = '1'
    for i in range(num - 1):
        cnt = 0
        new_string = []
        prev_c = None
        for c in string:
            if prev_c is not None and prev_c != c:
                new_string.append(str(cnt)+prev_c)
                cnt = 0
            cnt += 1
            prev_c = c
        new_string.append(str(cnt)+c)
        string = ''.join(new_string)
    return string
```